# How to list all namespaces in a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to figure out how to list all namespaces in a cluster:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/

something like:

```
kubectl describe cluster --namepaces -o json
```

anyone know how to list all the namespaces in a K8S/EKS cluster?

Answer (score 49):

```
$ kubectl get ns
$ kubectl describe ns
```

Also, you can use [kubens](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx/blob/master/kubens) to list and switch namespaces (on your local [KUBECONFIG](https://ahmet.im/blog/mastering-kubeconfig/))

```
 $ kubens
```

Answer (score 12):

Namespaces are an object like any other, so `kubectl get namespaces` will list them.  `kubectl describe namespaces` will print full details.

Comment: Why do I keep getting `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup something.eks.amazonaws.com on 10.10.0.2:53: no such host` . Thanks

Comment: use this command: az aks command invoke -g <resource group name> -n <cluster name> -c "kubectl get namespaces" @mdabdullah

Answer (score 0):

View namespaces in EKS cluster can be done as below:

via AWS management console :

```
 - Login to aws
 - search for eks service
 - select the cluster in eks service
 - select resources tab and click on all namespace dropdown. It will show all namespaces in the cluster
```

Via CLI :

set the kubeconfig of the cluster in aws-cli using below command

Command: `aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <cluster-name>`

Note: your aws role should have permission to fetch and set the kubeconfig.

List Namespace command :

command: `kubectl get ns`

Describe Namese command : (It will list namespaces along with labels, limits, resource quota)

Command : `kubectl describe ns`

Kubernetes Cluster - List/Describe Namespaces:

Command : `kubectl get ns`

Describe Namese command : (It will list namespaces along with labels, limits, resource quota)

Command : `kubectl describe ns`

Note: kubeconfig must set before running above commands.